# On the function $f(x,y)=x^2$ if $|x|<|y|$, $f(x,y)=y^2$ if $|x|\geq|y|$

Tags: continuity

We have this function defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x^2  &  \text{if $|x|<|y|$}\\
y^2  &  \text{if $|x|\geq|y|$}
\end{cases}
$$
How to study on $(a,a)$: the continuity, partial derivatives? Thank you.

I have an answer for the continuity:

1) Continuity: The problem is when $|x|=|y|$.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,a),(x,y)\in \{(x,y),|x|<|y|}\}{x^2}=a^2$$ and
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,a),(x,y)\in \{(x,y),|x|\geq|y|}\} {x^2}=a^2$$
then we obtain the continuity.

Answer (score 1):

As for continuity you are correct.
for differentiability you would like to show $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous. however they are not.
take the line $a=-b +2$ and the dot $(1,1)$ you will get:
$$\lim_{b\implies1^-}f_x(a,b)=2\neq 0 =\lim_{b\implies1^+}f_x(a,b)$$
You can generlize this idea to the whole line $(a,a)$.
Hence $f$ is not differentiable on the line $x=y$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The differentiability exist only for $a=0$?

Comment: Yes, it does. and for all $a\neq b$ $(a,b)$